# Is it possible to use custom TrueType fonts in a reportlab.graphics.Drawing?

Tags: python, reportlab

It appears to be quite easy to embed a TrueType font in a PDF document using `reportlab.pdfgen.canvas.Canvas`. However, I'm using the class `reportlab.graphics.Drawing` instead, since that gives me the option of saving the image as a PNG as well as a PDF.

I can't find any mention anywhere of using custom TrueType fonts with the `Drawing` class. Can it be done?

Comment: What have you tried? I'm assuming you've looked through the library code and found nothing that supports it?

Comment: @GGordonWorleyIII: I've checked the [automatically generated documentation](http://www.reportlab.com/apis/reportlab/dev/index.html), but it's completely empty. I haven't dared make an attempt at the code.

Comment: In my experience if you want to do something with ReportLab that isn't obvious, you're going to need to dive into the code. There's unfortunately not great documentation, even in the code, so it's certainly a bit of work to figure things out.

Comment: If you register the font (`pdfmetrics.registerFont`) is it not possible to use in both `reportlab.pdfgen.canvas.Canvas` and `reportlab.graphics.Drawing`?